# Meaning of the phrase "straight up" in context

Tags: meaning

Here it goes:

> "Many think that women are weak creatures, but it is just a **straight up** stereotype."

What is the meaning of the phrase "straight up" in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Straight up"** can mean obvious, blatant, or complete. It can also be used to express a superlative, or an emphasis on honesty. It is often used to say that something is absurd, and obviously shouldn't be believed. It is often used in informal speech, and highly stigmatized  in formal occasions. It can be used like,

> "I did not get a 62 in that test! That's straight up crazy!"
>
> "Not all gay men like Beyoncé! That's straight up the craziest stereotype I've ever heard of!"
>
> "The train was straight up 30 minutes late. Not even kidding."

In the first example, we are both denouncing the rumor as absurd and saying that it is **"Completely or totally crazy."** In the second example, we are saying that the stereotype is **"honestly the craziest stereotype I've ever heard of."** In the final example, we are using **"Straight up"** simply to emphasize honesty. We aren't really using it to replace another word.

Answer (score 0):

**Straight up** is usually used in a colloquial context meaning being honest or fair.

The [Macquaerie Dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/?word=straight%20up&search_word_type=Dictionary) states:

> adjective
>
> Colloquial 1.  honest; fair

However, in your sentence, it seems to mean something like *but that is a typical stereoptype*.